# wicket 1.6.6 spring security

Tags: java, spring-security, wicket-1.6

I am having troubles with migrating to Wicket 1.6.6

First of all, in version 1.6.6, the function `continueToOriginalDestination` does not return true or false.

Secondly, `locateByClassLoader` inside the  `org.apache.wicket.core.util.resource.locator.ResourceStreamLocator` does not exist.

Is there any exammple project I can use With wicket 1.6.6 and Spring Security version 3.1.0 or above?

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a nice blog about it here. http://www.idesign4all.nl/blog/?p=62 In this blogpost, the author describes by means of a tutorial how you can setup Wicket 1.5 to use Spring Security 3.1 for authentication and Wicket Auth/Roles for authorization.

Another tutorial is written here: http://javajeedevelopment.blogspot.nl/2011/03/integrating-spring-security-3-with.html
The author here writes about integrating Spring Security 3 with Wicket.

Also, a tutorial from some older versions of the applications can be found here: http://www.mkyong.com/wicket/wicket-spring-integration-example/ It might be worth a read.

Comment: i know to google as well :) it's the 1.6.x i migrate bto that couses problemes

Answer (score 0):

Since Wicket 1.6 continueToOriginalDestination does not return any value any more. For a discussion about it why it was changed have a look at the [mailing list](http://markmail.org/thread/dtfsthndjnziuuov)

Also make sure you read the [javadoc](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/Component.html#continueToOriginalDestination%28%29).

ResourceStreamLocator has been [cleaned up](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/migration-to-wicket-60.html#MigrationtoWicket6.0-ResourceStreamLocatorandResourceFinderhavebeencleanedup) in Wicket 1.6. (See this [commit](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/incubator-wicket-commits/201207.mbox/%3C20120703131419.3212AA597@tyr.zones.apache.org%3E) and the corresponding [ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-4617) to it).

Maybe that helps already a bit.